# How to typecast string to date in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, casting

I want to typecast the string to date format.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
data_source_df=spark.createDataFrame(
        data = [ ("1","2019.06.24 12:01:19")],
        schema=["id","input"])
#df.printSchema()
data_source_df.show()
```

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

data_source_df = data_source_df.withColumn("input", to_date("input", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

I tried the above code, it is typecasting to date but I'm getting null as resulting output.

```
+---+-----+
| id|input|
+---+-----+
|  1| null|
+---+-----+
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: `to_date` will require you to provide the format of the input string date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direction, which use `to_date()`, is correct,  but just change the format to `yyyy.MM.dd HH:MM:SS`, that is

```
data_source_df = data_source_df.withColumn("input", to_date("input", "yyyy.MM.dd HH:MM:SS"))
```

You null value is because of the incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
data_source_df = data_source_df.withColumn("input", to_date("input", "yyyy.MM.dd"))
```